# Prestashop - sorting product features with 01. 02. 03

Tags: prestashop

i sorted product features with 01. 02. 03. in front and now i don't know how to hide these unnecessary characters from block layered module.

I followed this topic: st_20_*p*_504198#entry504198">http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/9709-edit-features-order-list/page_*st*_20_*p*_504198#entry504198

to hide numbers from product and compare pages. But no succes with block layered.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed number with jquery. added function to blocklayered.js file.